# Converting 2D images to 3D

Tags: python, r, 3d

I was trying to convert 2D images to 3D by rotating them about the axes (like a circle to a sphere).
Currently my problem is that suppose I have two functions f(x) and g(x) both in one variable. I wish to make a plot of the functions and use rotation to get 3D plots. Based on the 3D plots I would distinguish between the two.

I think one way could be the work out the exact expressions mathematically for the new functions after rotation, but that can be computationally infeasible for not so reasonable functions.
Can someone please suggest a way to do it using suitable softwares?

Comment: What functions do you mean?

Comment: Have you looked at grDevices? it has `trans3d` , maybe have the opposite too.

Comment: what is the axis of rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `rgl` package (interface to openGL) in R and the `turn3d` function

```
## Define a function (ys must be positive, we are spinning about x-axis)
f <- function(x) 2*exp(-1/2*x) * (cos(pi*x) + sin(pi*x)) + 2
xs <- seq(0, 10, length=1000)
plot(xs, f(xs), type="l")
```

[image]

```
## Rotate about the x-axis
library(rgl)
res <- turn3d(xs, f(xs))
plot3d(res, alpha=.5)
snapshot3d("temp.png")
```

[image]